# HttpOnly Cookie based authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, redux, httponly

```js
export const login = (credentials) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post("/auth/login", credentials);
    dispatch(gotUser(data));
    socket.emit("go-online", data.id);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    dispatch(gotUser({ error: error.response.data.error || "Server Error" }));
  }
};
```

I have successfully sent a httpOnly cookie from the backend.... I not sure how I authenticate a user login in react.... Can anyone help me explain it?

I am having trouble understanding how cookie based authentication works with react and node.

```js
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // expects username and password in req.body
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    if (!username || !password)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username and password required" });

    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        username: req.body.username,
      },
    });

    if (!user) {
      console.log({ error: `No user found for username: ${username}` });
      res.status(401).json({ error: "Wrong username and/or password" });
    } else if (!user.correctPassword(password)) {
      console.log({ error: "Wrong username and/or password" });
      res.status(401).json({ error: "Wrong username and/or password" });
    } else {
      const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user.dataValues.id },
          process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
          { expiresIn: 86400 }
      );
      const options = {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: true
      }
      res.cookie("token", token, options);
      res.json({
        ...user.dataValues,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to do anything on your client except to set the `credentials` option for `fetch` that will cause the browser to send the cookie back to your browser with every request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#parameters

Comment: I have set my login as above if you want to see it.

Comment: Yes, that seems okay from what I can tell - you can validate it in your browser's DevTools.
My point is that **all** you have to do on your client side is make sure that you set `credentials: "include"` in your `fetch` calls and the cookie will be sent back to the server with those requests. You literally don't have to do anything else on your client side to handle all this, you can just validate the cookie on the server and that's it.